# how to differentiate between simple command and habit which which has been said in simple present tense?

Tags: grammar, tense, american-english, british-english

consider sentence:-

"You do this."

i can interpret this in two ways:-

1. i am asking someone to do something it is command.
2. i am talking about his usual habit like "he always does this"

then how to indicate in which sense i am talking in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You, close the door" is a command, and the comma represents what would be a slight but noticeable pause in speech.

"You close the door" would be spoken without a noticeable pause between "you" and "close." Such a sentence may be either a description of habitual or regular action or the historical present.

The example is highly artificial because it is a very brief sentence given without context. In practice, either the sentence itself or its context would usually give additional clues to the intended meaning.